# Error con slice select2.js

Tags: c#, mvc, controller, select2

Estoy teniendo problemas al llenar un combobox con [Select2](https://select2.github.io/)

Tengo mi JS:

```
$("#comboplatos").select2({
    placeholder: "Type to select a sponsor",
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    allowClear: true,
    style: "display: inline-block",
    width: 400,
    ajax: {
        cache: false,                      
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Admin/LlenarDestinoconJSON",
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                query: params.term,
                page: params.page// search term
            };

        },
        results: function (data) {
            return { results: data };
        }
    },
    formatResult: contractFormatResult,
    formatSelection: contractFormatSelection,
    escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }        
});
```

Y mi controlador es:

```
public JsonResult LlenarDestinoconJSON(string query)
    {
        var lista = CMM_PersonaNeg.Instancia.Listar(query);
        var JSonLista = Json(lista.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return JSonLista;
    }
```

Al ejecutar la aplicación, mediante el debug puedo obtener los datos que deseo, pero no me muestra nada en el combo y me aparece este error en consola:

> select2.js:4008 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

No tengo idea de como poder solucionarlo, busque en varios foros pero no encontré alguna solución que pueda ayudarme.

Espero que me puedan decir si algo está mal en mi código o falta agregar algo.

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema puede estar en como recibes el `json` o la estructura del `json`

Si el `json` que recibes no contiene al menos un identificador `id` y `text` no mostrara nada te sugiero que modifiques tu `json` desde `results`

```
ajax: {
    ...,
    //si con results no funciona probar con processResults
    //processResults: function (data, params) {
    results: function (data, params) {
        //recorriendo el json pare crear uno con la informacion esperada
        data.results = data.map(function (obj) {
          return {
            "text": obj.Nombre,
            "id": obj.id
          };
        });
        //retornando los valores esperados en el formato esperado por el plugin
        return { results: data.results };
    }
},
```

Es necesario ese cambio debido a que el `json` que espera el plugin contenga al menos lo siguiente:

```
{
  results: [
    {id:1, text:"Hola Mundo"},//Puede llevar otros parámetros pero no los reconocerá 
    {id:2, text:"Probando Json"}
  ]
}
```